How to track if a document is newly created in a SharePoint document library or moved from other document library Across Sites?
I am trying to track documents moved from one SharePoint Document Library to another, potentially across different sites.
Here are the details of what I'm looking for:
Scenario: Documents are moved using standard SharePoint methods (e.g., Move-To option in the command bar).
Requirement: I want to identify when a document is moved, its original location, and its destination.
Environment: SharePoint Online with access to REST APIs, PnP Core SDK, or similar tools for customization.
Questions:

Is there any native SharePoint feature, audit logs, or API to track such "move" events across sites?
Any suggestions for best practices to maintain a history of document movements?


To track if a document is newly created or moved in a SharePoint document library, you can utilize the activity feed feature in SharePoint. When a file is moved, updates will appear in the activity feed of both the source and target libraries. This allows you to see the movement of documents and can help identify their original and new locations.
Reference:View the activity feed of a document library

